# Unable to create a project with native code

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I've been searching around and already reinstalled node, react-native-cli and watchman.
I'm using an emulator and the setup are:

```
macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
react-native: 0.57.1
node v10.11.0
watchman 4.9.0
```

Everytime I create a project using:

```
react-native init [project_name]
```

I get this red screen:

[image]

I've already tried this:

```
This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/ivofreitas/Projects/JavascriptWorkspace/react-native/YourProject/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:209:1301)
```

Tried to create with an earlier version of react like:

```
react-native init [YourProject] --version react-native@0.55.4
```

I did this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started tutorial again and reinstall everything with no success

Comment: What OS are you using? What package managers are you using? If you're using npm try `npm cache clean --force` or if yarn do `yarn cache clean && yarn global cache clean`.

Comment: added the info 10.13.6
used npm cache clean --force inside project folder and still having the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found this post on github

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21310

It solves the problem by:

```
npm add @babel/runtime
npm install
```

As said in the link, it shouldn't work like that.